# Gradle error: Build_a1sbpzr1x108u5hpi16ccvku3$_run_closure2@6142ebd9

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Good day guys, i plan to run the project on build tools version 24.0.1 but the gradles keep showing this errors. Does anyone encounter this errors before?

**Messages Gradle sync:**

```
Error:(19, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_a1sbpzr1x108u5hpi16ccvku3$_run_closure2@2cbc6cb3] on root project 'CardDemo-master' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:D:\New folder\CardDemo-master\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
}
dependencies {
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.delaroystudios.carddemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `android` block in the top level gradle file and instead change the value of `buildToolsVersion` in the app gradle file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```